# 2D Array prints out symbols

Tags: c, arrays

I'm trying to make a tictactoe game, but when I try to print the 2d array which I used as the field, the first row looks fine but the 2nd & 3rd are having an issue.

[The output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqC8U.png)

How do I fix that? Heres the code for the output:

```
    void ausgabe(int b[][3]) // Output
{
    int i, k;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        for (k = 0; k < 3; k++)
            printf("%2c |", b[i][k]);
        printf("\n------------\n");
    }

}
```

and here for the 2d array:

```
char a[3][3] = { {0,0,0}, {0,0,0}, {0,0,0} };
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `a` is an array of `char` but you're casting it to an array of `int` in `ausgabe`. Thus, when you index the array (`b[i][k]`) you're accessing memory that hasn't been initialised, giving you those strange characters.

Comment: Well, it works when I change it to `int`, but I want it to replace a element with X and O later.

Comment: Great! Adding 'X' and 'O' later will be no problem. Please accept this answer and then ask something more specific.